# Delphi connect to online sql database

Tags: mysql, delphi, firemonkey

This question may be very easy but I really cannot find a real answer online. I already know that I can connect to a sqlite database stored in my computer with FireDac but now I want to move on an online sql server.

I own a domain with a sql server inside.

[image]

This is my configuration and it tells me `Unknown configuration host`. I need to connect to my sql database online. Is FireDAC the real solution?

---

I have this kind of connection string server-side:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=mysql.netsons.com;dbname=caorobwq_worldcup', 'username', 'password');
```

Comment: Have you checked that the SQL server is reachable from outside? This is usually not the case for the average website due to security reasons.

Comment: Can you connect to the MySQL server using the command line client? NB default installations of MySQL only allow connections from the local machine, not a remote client. You should consider the security implications of connecting remotely.

Comment: I use FireDAC quite a bit for connecting to servers on my network and it works well.

Comment: As Uwe says, this is not how it is usually done. Normally, you would have an app on that server which is all that is allowed to conenct to the databse, and clients would communicate with that I recommend a RESTful interface).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect to such server, but you should not expose it this way. Create another, application layer that will use your database server as a *local* storage. It's called [**three tier architecture**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture).

[image]